# Paginate date-specific results from an API with React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to show some news in my React app using Redux.

The problem is that I want to show the news for individual dates and I want to paginate the news.

In my API I print

```
{
  pagination: {
    count: 1000,
    size: 10,
    page: 1,
    pages: 100
  },
  news: [
    ..
  ]
}
```

I know how to make a simple pagination, but I don't know how the API should work if I want to be able to show news for different dates in my app.

Until now (without dates), I have just kept a state `news` and `pagination` in my Redux reducer, and then checked if the page number equals the total number of pages to determine whether it should try loading more news.

But now that I potentially have many different dates and I want to keep all the news in the Redux store, I don't know how to structure it.

I can keep my API as it is, since filtering with GET parameter `?date=15-09-2017` will just decrease the number of news in the API result.

But would it still be possible to just keep all the news in an array in a `news` variable in my reducer or do I have to structure it to be something like

```
news: {
  '15-09-2017': {
    news: [...],
    pagination: {}
  },
  ...
}
```

in order to keep track of the pagination for every single date?

Comment: Do you mean you also need separate page for each date?

Comment: I need to be able to press "load more" and then append the news to the already-loaded news for every single date

Answer (score 8):

A think a structure where you store your your news by id and ids per date would be good and flexible structure:

```
{
    "byId": {
        "10": { /* News */ },
        "14": { /* News */ },
        /* ... */
    },
    "listsByDate": {
        "2017-08-24": {
            "total": 100,
            "pageSize": 10,
            "page": 2,
            "items": [
                10,
                14,
                /* ... */
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can implement simple selectors for this structure:

```js
const getNewsById = (state, id) => state.byId[id];

const getListByDate = (state, date) => state.listByDate[date];

const getPageOfList = (state, data) => getListByDate(state, date).page

/* ... */

const getNewsByDate = (state, date) => {
    return getListByDate(state, data).items.map((id) => {
        return getNewsById(state, id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I append news to `listsByDate[date].items` in my reducer?

Comment: Because redux expect no mutation of objects you have to create a new array. You can simply do it with `newArr = [].concat(oldArray, [ newItemToAppend ]);`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to keep storing all news in a single place (`news` in your reducer), and use [selectors](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) to compute derived data.

To achieve this, you will need to store the current date (I suppose it's a some kind of filter in your app) in Redux store, so it can be used in your selector.

So your reducer will look like:

```
{
  news: [], // you can keep all the news here
  date: '15-09-2017', // selected date
  page: 1, // current page
  pagination: {
    '15-09-2017': { ... }, // pagination info by date.
    // You will need this only if you use the classic pager (with page numbers in UI)
    // it's not needed in case of infinite scroll
  }
}
```

And selectors:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

// select all news
const newsSelector = () => (state) => state.get('news');

// select date
const dateSelector = () => (state) => state.get('date');

// select page
const pageSelector = () => (state) => state.get('page');

// select news by date
const newsByDateSelector = () => createSelector(
  newsSelector(),
  dateSelector(),
  (news, date, page) => news.filter((newsItem) => newsItem.get('date') === date)
);

const pageSize = 10;
const newsByDatePagedSelector = () => createSelector(
  newsByDateSelector(),
  pageSelector(),
  (news, page) => news.slice(pageSize  * (page - 1), pageSize * page)
);
```

Then you can use `newsByDatePagedSelector` selector to get the needed news in your container:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';

export class NewsContainer extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    // news by selected date are not loaded yet
    if (!this.props.news) {
      this.loadNews();
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // user navigated to the next page
    if (this.props.news && !nextProps.news) {
      this.loadNews();
    }
  }

  loadNews() {
    // fetch next 10 news from server
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        this.props.news.map((newsItem) => ...)
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  news: newsByDatePagedSelector(),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewsContainer);
```

When user reach the last news by some date, you can request next 10 news  from your API as usual with filter `?date=15-09-2017` and put them to your store. Redux and reselect will bring them to `NewsContainer` as `newsByDate` prop.

Comment: But how do I keep the page number? If I at one page keep clicking load more until I am at page 10 with a total number of 100 (10 * 10) news, then if I go to another date, I will have to reset the page number to 1 to load the first 10 news at that date. But now if I go back to the first date, I don't want to load the first 100 news as I have already loaded these?

Comment: I'm sorry, at first I missed the part about pagination. I updated the answer

Comment: I don't need the regular page number pagination, but I still don't know how determine whether there are more pages to be loaded for the separate dates to ensure that I won't call the API once everything is loaded

Comment: Also, how do I change the page number? Should I make a redux action that fetches the new news and set the page number? Or should I set the page number separately?